# Класс для хранения текущих данных игры

Tags: android

**Нужно:**
хранить данные(уровень, кол-во одного параметра, кол-во другого параметра и так штук 20 разных).

**Я думаю так:** создать класс-синглтон, к которому буду обращаться через getInstance, в классе будет хранится объект Игра в единственном экземпляре со всеми нужными мне полями и на протяжении игры я буду эти поля менять. При выходе из игры - сохранять.

**На сколько такой подход правильный ?**

(*п.с. где-то когда-то читал, что не стоит использовать так класс-синглтон, но не могу найти статью*)

Comment: Как по мне - все правильно. Только сохранять лучше не при выходе, а при каждом изменении данных. Можно просто сериализовать класс, и записывать в `SharedPreferences`

Comment: @metalurgus, о, на счет сериализации это хорошая идея, чтобы каждое значение не писать под отдельным ключом )